# not able to fetch the data from rrd file

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

I am using RRDTool version 1.2.30 on windows platform, i have one .rrd file  and when i tried to fetch data using 'rrdtool fetch' it is giving me following error.

> ERROR: the RRD does not contain an RRA
>   matching the chosen CF

on firing following command

> rrdtool fetch usage.rrd AVERAGE -r
>   3600 -s 1298264400 -e 1298350800

i really don't know whats wrong with this even when i tried to view the data in xml using rrdtool dump over usage.rrd its is showing me following error.

```
<!-- Round Robin Database Dump --><rrd> <version> 0003 </version
        <step> 2 </step> <!-- Seconds -->
        <lastupdate> 0 </lastupdate> <!-- 1970-01-01 05:30:00 In
e -->

        <ds>
                <name>  </name>
                <type>  </type>
                <minimal_heartbeat> 0 </minimal_heartbeat>
                <min> 5.9287877501e-322 </min>
                <max> NaN </max>

                <!-- PDP Status -->
                <last_ds> LAST </last_ds>
                <value> 5.0000000000e-001 </value>
                <unknown_sec> 1 </unknown_sec>
        </ds>

        <ds>
                <name>  </name>
                <type>  </type>
                <minimal_heartbeat> 0 </minimal_heartbeat>
                <min> 5.9287877501e-322 </min>
                <max> NaN </max>

                <!-- PDP Status -->
                <last_ds>  </last_ds>
                <value> 2.4703282292e-323 </value>
                <unknown_sec> 2016 </unknown_sec>
        </ds>

<!-- Round Robin Archives --></rrd>
ERROR: unknown data acquisition function ''
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

my guess is, that this rrd file was created by some other copy of rrdtool ... under windows it is possible to create slightly incompatible versions of rrdtool by compiling them with different compilers :-(

Answer (score 1):

Rrd database created at Linux is not compatible with rrdtool (same version) at Windows. Tested on version 1.3.8.

You must export rrd to xml at Linux:

```
rrdtool dump file.rrd > file.xml
```

and import it at Windows:

```
rrdtool.exe restore file.xml file.rrd
```

If your locale representation of floating point number differs between Linux (1.234e+05) and Windows (1,234e+05), you must convert numbers in file.xml before import.